# Different css url in debug and release

Tags: html, css

I have a web application with urls in the css files. In production I have an optimized css file which is located in a different location relatively to the images folder. 
For example:

In developement:

```
.someClass{
   background: url("../images/....);
}
```

In production:

```
.someClass{
   background: url("../../images/....);
}
```

Obviously I want the images to work in both cases, is there a solution for that? (besides making sure that the css has the same relative position)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than triversing up directories with .. you could use root relative URLS which start with a forward slash (/) which refer to the root web directory and type out the remainder of the address.  Using root relative URLs should work in both instances for you.

Comment: That would be great but the problem is that we have two applications, let's call them A and B and they both use the css files. So in A the url should be url(/A/images/...) and in B it should be url(/B/images/...)

Comment: beginning with a forward slash specifies the root web directory.  If using two different images you should use two different classes.  If both are using the same image, then the paths should not be affected because your specifying the path from the root directory which is not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [reworkcss](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework/) in your project (which runs on node.js/gulp) there is a plugin that does what you need: [rework-plugin-url](https://github.com/reworkcss/rework-plugin-url/)

Fragment from gulp file:

```
.pipe(rework(
  reworkPluginUrl(function(url) {
    return '../' + url;
  })
))
```

As part of your build, the following CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(../images/bg.png);
}
```

will be transformed into:

```
body {
  background: url(../../images/bg.png);
}
```